# A question about complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

The famous power series $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots$ converges normally in the whole complex plane $\mathbb C$ and mathematicians chose to call
$$\exp(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

now my question is:

Why, they where sure that the above limit wasn't a rational function? In a nutshell, who does ensure that there aren't two polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that $\frac{p}{q}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ ?

Comment: You may be interested in my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170373/how-do-we-know-taylors-series-works-with-complex-numbers

Comment: I think I may have posted the simplest answer.  But it relies on knowing certain basic facts about the function defined by the powers series, which my answer doesn't prove.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several possible ways to eliminate the possibility of a rational function, for example:

It is not hard to prove that $\exp(z)$ tends to infinity faster than any power of $x$.

Also, looking at the function in the complex plane, it is periodic, and it is not hard to prove that a rational function can never be periodic.

Answer (score 8):

A rational function has a limit as $z\to\infty$ (either a complex number or $\infty$). On the other hand, $\lim_{z\to\infty}e^z$ does not exist.

A different reasoning. Since $e^z$ has no singularities other than $\infty$, if it were rational, it should be a (non-constant) polynomial. But a nonconstant polynomial vanishes at some point, while $e^z\ne0$ for any complex number $z$.

Comment: +1 for the second argument. This is a new thought for me...

Comment: Most rational functions do not have finite limits as $z\to\infty$!

Comment: @MichaelHardy How do you define "most"? If $R(z)$ has an infinite limit at $\infty$, then $1/R(z)$ has a finite limit. So it seems hat here as many rational functions with a finite limit as with an $\infty$ limit.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre : OK, let's say "most" means "half".

Answer (score 8):

$$\exp(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Let's assume that we have 2 polynomials and we express $e^x=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$

The polynomials are
$$P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$

$$Q(x)=b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_0$$

$(e^x)'=e^x=\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)'$

We assumed $e^x=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$
Thus,

$$e^x=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)'$$

$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)'=\left(\frac{P'(x)Q(x)- P(x)Q'(x)}{Q^2(x)}\right)$$

$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P'(x)Q(x)- P(x)Q'(x)}{Q^2(x)}$$

$$P(x)Q(x)=P'(x)Q(x)- P(x)Q'(x)$$

$$P(x)(Q(x)+Q'(x))=P'(x)Q(x)$$

$$P(x)(Q(x)+Q'(x))=(a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0)(b_mx^m+(mb_m+b_{m-1})x^{m-1}+\cdots)=a_nb_mx^{n+m}+\cdots$$

$$P'(x)Q(x)=(na_nx^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1)(b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_0)=na_nb_mx^{n+m-1}+\cdots$$

As we see $P(x)(Q(x)+Q'(x))=P'(x)Q(x)$ cannot be equal because their degrees are not equal. The degree of polynomial $P(x)(Q(x)+Q'(x))$ is $m+n$, The degree of other polynomial $P'(x)Q(x)$ is $m+n-1$ . Thus it is impossible to find $e^x=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where  $P(x)$  and $Q(x)$ are polynomials.

Comment: Very nice! Only as a matter of taste I would leave the derivation at the "symmetric" stage $P(x)Q(x) = P'(x)Q(x) - P(x)Q'(x) $ and would then focus on the highest exponents of $x$, which is on the lhs $n+m$ and on the rhs $\max((n-1)+m,n+(m-1))=n+m-1$ which I would see immediately without need of resorting to the explicite polynomial representation.

Answer (score 3):

Another argument that can easily be checked with power series: 
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\right)'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$$  which cannot be true for no non-zero rational functions.

Answer (score 2):

If a rational function of $z$ has a limit as $z\to-\infty$, then it has the same limit as $z\to\infty$.  If you can show that *this* function approaches $0$ as $z\to-\infty$ and approaches $\infty$ as $z\to\infty$, then you've shown it doesn't behave at all like a rational function.